# Need some help on RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I need help creating a regEx for checking that inputs are

1. 17 characters long
2. May not contain special characters or white space
3. May not contain I, O, or Q
4. Only capital letters allowed.

For the first, 17 characters part, I've solved it (according to the HW requirements) by using `if(str.length() == 17)`, and I've sort of understand how to do the excluding characters part. Here's what I have so far

`String regEx = "\\S^[I,O,Q][A-Z]"`

but this does not work. I'm kind of stumped on how to get it working. I know that `\\S` means that it cannot include any white spaces. The `^` means that it should exclude `I,O,Q` (or so I think it should, not sure), and then `[A-Z]` means it should all be in capital letters.

Can anyone help me figure out how to properly make the regEx for this?

Side notes, I've looked at other regEx questions relating to removing special characters, but it only excludes a few `$<>@&`, how do I get it to exclude all of them?

Thanks

Comment: Note that `"Need some help on RegEx"` is a poor title for a StackOverflow question as it tells us nothing whatsoever of use, other than you're having a problem with regex -- and for that add a [tag:regex] tag to your question (which I've done). Please consider using much more informative question titles, ones that summarize your actual problem. Doing this will help you get better help.

Comment: `[ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ]{17}` (or `[A-HJ-NPR-Z]{17}` (I think))

Comment: In regex, the `^` character is overloaded. Outside of a character class `[]` it means "start of the string", inside the character class, it means "not these". Moving the `^` to inside the character class won't solve your regex problem, but I thought you should know. Go with what @SeanBright has.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[A-HJ-NPR-Z]{17}
```

I have created a list of random words with length 17, so you can see this regex in action:

https://regex101.com/r/w7zMEY/1

try yourself adding more random words

---

> Side notes, I've looked at other regEx questions relating to removing
>   special characters, but it only excludes a few $<>@&, how do I get it
>   to exclude all of them?

with this regex

```
[A-HJ-NPR-Z]{17}
```

you are matching only capital letters, except for I,O,Q...
any other char it's excluded

---

Note that you may need to surround the regex with something else...
that depends on the context in which your are looking for those words; for example:

If you want to match that pattern, but a sole word per line,
you can use:

```
^[A-HJ-NPR-Z]{17}$
```

see here: https://regex101.com/r/w7zMEY/2

if you want to match that pattern, in a 'random' place on a line,
but only if it is not surrounded by other capital letters, you can use:

```
(?<=[^A-Z])[A-HJ-NPR-Z]{17}(?=[^A-Z])
```

see here: https://regex101.com/r/w7zMEY/3

Comment: I like this one.